# Reading Serial Data Using readBytes() and Use of Serial.read()

Tags: serial, arduino-due

I'm trying to mix `Serial.read()` and `Serial.readBytes()` when reading over one of the Serial ports on my Arduino Due.
I thought that using `Serial.read()` would clear what is on the serial, and then subsequent reads by `readBytes()` would not pick up what has already been read by the Serial.

The main reason I'm trying this approach is because large Serial reads can be unstable using the Arduino supplied `Serial.read()` - I've checked the Serial buffer with a logic analyzer, so I know that the data is on the Serial line, but `Serial.read()` drops some bytes.

Hence why I want to use `Serial.readBytes()`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```cpp
#define FIXED_LENGTH 10
char * buffer, * bp;
int index, i, bufSize;
while(1)
  {
  if(Serial3.available())
  {
    data = Serial3.read();
    Serial.print(data,HEX); //Check the data received
    buffer[index]=data;
    index++;

    if(index == FIXED_LENGTH){
       //...code to calculate bufSize from buffer...//
       bp = (char*)calloc(1,bufSize); //calloc bp size
       Serial3.readBytes(bp,bufSize); //read the rest of what's on the serial
       break;
    }
  }
  }
```

I get the correct output from the first part of the code - that is, it correctly calculates `bufSize` from buffer. But when I try to store the following length into bp, it gives me more or less the first output that I have already read on the first few passes!

Example:

Data coming in over `Serial3.read()` `[10]`: `0123456789`

The next characters in `Serial3` are `[6]`: `ABCDEF`

Stored into `bp` using `Serial3.readBytes()` `[6]`: `000045`

Do I need to flush `Serial3` before attempting to read the next set of bytes off of it? Do I need to wait/set a timeout before advancing to the next operation?

Comment: You did not initialize `buffer`: you are going to corrupt your memory.

Comment: Sorry but your code is full of bugs, its going to blow up in you face.  index needs initialising, you don't check to see if the calloc fails, you don't free the calloc.  I would approach it a different way, use readByte into a static buffer of fixed size, process the data, read again.

Comment: You're right, this code would be full of bugs, but it's just a snippet as part of a larger portion of code. Please assume that I am properly initializing buffer and setting up the rest of the variables correctly. My question is dealing with readBytes and reading from the Serial line.

Comment: You should probably check out [create a minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to **enable** people to help you.